# How can I make a simple user profile URL with Express and Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I want to make URL for users profiles similar to Twitter or Facebook:

`https://twitter.com/<id_or_something>`

`https://www.facebook.com/<id_or_something>`

With something like this routes:

```
router.get("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
// Code...
});
```

And the Id has to be something that I can make with MongoDB like some custom ID by the user itself or some ID generated by MongoDB.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where u are stuck so that we can help you.

Comment: I will say that you just need to have something belonging to the user and unique (mongo ID / username for example). Find the document with this parameters(req.params.id) and send back the document to the client.

Comment: @cagliostro It actually worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did this and worked:

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {

    const userUD = req.params.id

    User.findOne({'nickname: userID'})
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
        res.render('user.hbs', {
            name: doc.name,
            nick: doc.nickname
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```